# How to add ONLY mysql database backup permission for a user in mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I need to add only mysql database table backup permission to one new mysql user account. My mysql version is 5.6. I've tried below command but its not working. Could someone please help?

`GRANT SELECT, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES, RELOAD, SHOW VIEW ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test123';`

Answer (score 0):

There are just two commands you need for this:

```
GRANT LOCK TABLES, SELECT ON DATABASE_NAME.* TO 'BACKUP_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Followed by:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not worked. Got the below error.  ``` mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'liquibaseuser'@'%' to database 'automation_suite' when selecting the database
 ```